# High load on Xen guests

Tags: virtualization, xen, xenserver, high-load

We're facing a weird issue with a freshly installed Xen (4.2) system.

The server is an [Intel SR1690WB](http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/server-systems/server-system-sr1690wbr.html) equipped with 4x1Tb HDD and with a [RS2BL040](http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/servers/raid/raid-controller-rs2bl.html) RAID card which configured to use RAID10.

The problem is that any newly spawned paravirtualized guest OS (Debian Squeeze) is working with very high load (70-80% use of CPU, mostly caused by `events/0` or `events/1`) no matter what they're doing (serving a dynamic page, or just simply downloading an iso file).

Each guest configured to use 2 CPU cores and 4gb RAM.

Just hoping there's some misconfiguration on the Dom0, but what can cause these terrible loads?

Please let me know if i can clarify my question.

Comment: How much of that "CPU load" is actually iowait?

Comment: @ErikA iostat gives me 0.09 %iowait.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fortunately the problem was found in our configuration.

After pinning a CPU core to Dom0 (instead of starting with the `nosmp` parameter) in grub options with

`GRUB_CMDLINE_XEN_DEFAULT="dom0_mem=1024M dom0_max_vcpus=1 dom0_vcpus_pin"`

All of the guest OS's are running healthy and fast. :)